# Matlab assignin

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide

I new with Matlab GUI, and there is 'Gaussian kernel size:[7x7; 9x9; 11x11]' that I want to take a user-entrance from keyboard using 'assignin' function. 
would you please let me know how to perform this?

```
th= str2double(get(handles.edit10,'String'));
assignin('base','user_kernel',th)
```

Comment: Avoid the `assignin` command, work within the workspace you're already in, you probably just want `input` if you want user input...

Comment: I agree with Wolfie. But also: what is the problem with your code? Error message? Wrong result? Please see [mre].

Comment: There was no major mistake or error. However i wanted to make it possible to take user input. It did not work so i used 'Pop-up-menu' for different cases.